# Hacer dos Querys en un controlador con Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Estoy intentando hacer dos consultas desde el controlador con `codeigniter`, os paso el código

```
$municipio_recogido = $_GET['value'];

$fecha_Recogida = $_GET['fechita'];

$datoss= $this->db->query("CALL spMostrarPeliculas2('$fecha_Recogida','$municipio_recogido')");
echo json_encode($datoss->result());
```

Mi pregunta es, como hago otra consulta en el mismo controlador, necesito sacar una lista de películas y otra de conciertos...

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->trans_start();    

    $peliculas= $this->db->query("CALL spMostrarPeliculas('$fecha_Recogida','$municipio_recogido');")->result();
    $conciertos= $this->db->query("CALL spMostrarConciertos('$fecha_Recogida','$municipio_recogido');")->result();

$this->db->trans_complete();


$respuesta = [
   "peliculas"=>$peliculas,
   "conciertos"=>$conciertos
];

echo json_encode($respuesta);
```

Simplemente añadiendo otra consulta normal, la unica diferencia es que para devolver los datos hace falta juntarlos,esta es la opcion mas simple, tambien se pueden filtrar u ordenar antes de devolverlos.